# Opening ViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have another ViewController inside the same story board to which I want to switch by clicking a button. The problem is when I try to control-Drag the second view controller to create an Outlet inside the ViewController.m file of the primary viewcontroller, an outlet isn't created.

*In Android we can open a new Activity with different UI from inside of another activity*. I am sure same can be achieved in iOS as well, so my question is **how can I create an outlet of the second view Controller and open it programmatically**?

Comment: Using storyboards? Then you can create `segues`

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in iOS to create an `IBOutlet` from one `ViewController` to another `ViewController`, But you can use a `UIStoryboardSegue` for the purpose.

I will suggest you to follow [Tutorial: Storyboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1) from Apple Documentation. It will help you understand how ViewControllers are actually connected.

Answer (score 1):

Opening `SecondViewController` programmatically is possible by using `Storyboard Identifier`, You need to provide storyboard identifier name for the class you want to switch to, see this image [image], in my demo i have used `secondViewController`

Now use this code inside your buttonClick event method.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    SecondViewController *secondViewController =  (SecondViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];

    // Use this to show your UIViewController in modal transition.
    [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    // Use this to show your UIViewController in push transition with navigation controller
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

Viewcontroller*homeVC;
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        UIStoryboard *storyBoard;

        storyBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        homeVC=(HomeVC*)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"];


        [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: I believe that calling `self.storyboard` will be faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you cannot do this.
To override and launch VC and keep it's properties you can:

First, create segue between viewControllers: Zoom out the view by double clicking the background of interface builder. Ctrl+drag from one VC to another and choose type of segue (e.g. show).

Than create action for button, in which you can:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier" sender:self];
```

After that, in `-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` check identifier of segue, set new yourCustomClassViewController and voila!

```
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"myIdentifier"]) {
        myCustomClassViewController *myCustomVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        myCustomVC.oldProfile = newProfile;
}
```